# Members of finite field with equal Norm and Trace

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, field-trace

The setting of the problem I'm trying to solve is as follows:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $k \geq 1$. How many pairs $x, y \in \mathcal F_p^k$ satisfy $\text{Tr}(y) = N(x)$?

My first intuition tells me there are $\mathcal F_p^k$ such pairs, since for every $y \in \mathcal F_p^k$, with $\text{Tr}(y) = A$, there is an $x \in \mathcal F_p^k$ with $N(x) = B$ so that $\hat{x} = \frac{A}{B} \cdot x \in \mathcal F_p^k$, and $N(\hat{x}) = \frac{A}{B} \cdot N(x) = A = \text{Tr}(y)$

But I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Are we talking about the so called absolute trace/norm respectively? That is, $Tr,N:\Bbb{F}_{p^k}\to\Bbb{F}_p$? If so you may benefit from the following hint. By linearity of the trace, each element of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is the trace of exactly $p^{k-1}$ elements of the bigger field $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$. Apply this to $N(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: A notational nitpick: Assuming you are talking about the field of $p^k$ elements, then that $p^k$ should be in the subscript position entirely. The way to achieve that with TeX is to enclose that power in braces. I used `\Bbb{F}_{p^k}` to get $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$. Feel free to use a different font for that F, if you are used to something else!

Comment: Thanks for the great direction @JyrkiLahtonen!
I understand I can say for each X it's norm must be the trace of $p^{k-1}$ elements. But what can I say about how many Xs have the same norm? since it's not linear. That way I can determine how many pairs x,y there are .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\mathrm{Tr}:\Bbb{F}_{p^k}\to\Bbb{F}_p$ is known to be $\Bbb{F}_p$-linear and surjective. By rank-nullity its kernel has dimension $k-1$ as a vector space over the prime field, and for all $z\in\Bbb{F}_p$ we know that there are exactly $p^{k-1}$ elements $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}(x)=z$.

Because the norm map is also a function $N:\Bbb{F}_{p^k}\to \Bbb{F}_p$ it follows that for every $y\in\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ there are exactly $p^{k-1}$ choices of $x\in\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ such that the equation
$$N(y)=\mathrm{Tr}(x)$$ is satisfied.

> Consequently the number of pairs $(x,y)\in\Bbb{F}_{p^k}^2$ such that $N(y)=\mathrm{Tr}(x)$ is equal to $p^{k-1}\cdot p^k=p^{2k-1}$.

---

Two concluding remarks:

- The same result holds for *any* function $g:\Bbb{F}_{p^k}\to\Bbb{F}_p$ in place of the norm map.
- In many other problems we also need to use the distribution of values of the norm map. It is well known that $y=0$ is the only element of $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}$ with $N(y)=0$. Also, when restricted to the multiplicative groups $N$ is a surjective homomorphism. Implying that it takes every possible non-zero value $z\in\Bbb{F}_p^*$ exactly $d=(p^k-1)/(p-1)=1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^{k-1}$ times. The simplest way of seeing this is to use the fact that $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}^*$ is a cyclic group, and $N(y)=y^d$ for all $y$.