# Solutions of a polynomial involving norm and trace over $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$

Tags: polynomials, normed-spaces, finite-fields, trace

Consider in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$ the functions norm and trace $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^3}|\mathbb{F}_{q}},\mathrm{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^3}|\mathbb{F}_{q}}\,:\mathbb{F}_{q^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{q}$ and let $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}_{q^3}$. How many solutions can have the polynomial $
\mathrm{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^3}|\mathbb{F}_{q}}(\lambda x^3)=\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{F}_{q^3}|\mathbb{F}_{q}}(x)$?

Note: from computer tests the only possible case seem to be the trivial case $x=0$.

Comment: Are you sure that $q$ shouldn't be $p$ (usual notation for a prime number) ?

Comment: Related (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3476021)

Comment: @Jean no reason why $q$ shouldn't be a power of a prime.

Comment: Unfortunately knowing the points such that $\mathrm{N}(x)=\mathrm{Tr}(x)$ does not seem to be useful, i.e. this question seem to be more complicated. 
In any case $q=p^k$, I don't see the point of restricting to prime fields.

Comment: Which field have you  tested this with? When $q=2$, the norm is equal to $1$ for all non-zero $x\in\Bbb{F}_8$, and, as cubing is a permutation of the bigger field, there will be four choices of $x$ such that the trace is also equal to $1$.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about the origin of this problem. Without cubing you could be trying to calculate the number of irreducible cubics of some kind or.... ?

Comment: Assuming $q\not\equiv1\pmod3$ then $\Bbb{F}_{q^3}^*$ is the direct product of $\Bbb{F}_q^*$ and $S=$ the kernel of your (relative) norm map. Every non-zero $x$ from the bigger field can thus be uniquely written in the form $x=ys$ with $y$  from the smaller field and $s\in S$. We have $N(x)=y^3$ and $T(\lambda x^3)=y^3 T(\lambda s^3)$. Given that under these conditions cubing is a permutation of $S$ we simply want to enumerate the solutions of $T(\lambda s)=1$. There should be a way. Possibly I need more Laphroaig to make progress. Possibly I need less...

Comment: You are right, actually my question makes sense only for $q>2$. Thank you for the hint, I will think about it and if it leads to a solution I will write it here! In any case this equation comes from an algebraic surface that I am studying, in particular it is connected to its singularieties.